# Temporary disable drag-and-drop

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-recyclerview, swipe

I'm using `ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback` to implement swipe and drag to drop in `RecyclerView`. I know how to disable these features for specific type of ViewHolder at all, but how can I do it temporary so I can turn it on/off from activity?

Comment: Post what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply override:

```
@Override
public boolean isItemViewSwipeEnabled() {
    return mIsSwipeEnabled;
}
```

In your `ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback`.